# Is it possible to get the current location and make an api call every 5 seconds in flutter (background and foreground)

Tags: flutter

I want to do this using lets say start and stop button.

when pressed start button the current location should be fetched and passed as a parameter to an api call. It should trigger to send the location data to server every 5 seconds.

The api call should trigger even if I minimise the app or navigate to another screen.
When pressed stop button the location data and api call should stop

how can I achieve that?
I've tried using geolocator to fetch current location and [workmanger](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager) to handle background task but workmanager seems to have the limit of 15 min minimum.
I've looked into [cron](https://pub.dev/packages/cron) but it has the limit of 1 min.
There is another one [flutter_background_geolocation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation) but it's paid.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: checkout this answer it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/74979446/19292778